# Yii PHP - JSON encoding active records turns ints and booleans into strings

Tags: activerecord, yii

In my database I have a friends table that has the following structure:

- id (int)
- user_a (int)
- user_b (int)
- accepted (tinyint)

I have an active record query that looks like this:

```
$friends = Friend::model()->findAll('user_a=:userId AND accepted IS true', array(':userId' => $this->user->id));
$this->sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($friends), 'application/json');
```

And I get back the following API response:

*[{"id":"2","user_a":"14","user_b":"3","accepted":"1"}]*

CJSON::encode seems to be turning everything into a string, why is this?  Is there a way to return the ints as numbers and tinyints as booleans?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CJSON::encode() does not turn variables to strings - but findAll() does. If you dump $friends models attributes you will see it. You can do something like this to deal with it:

```
protected function afterFind()
{
    $this->id = (int) $this->id;
    $this->user_a = (int) $this->user_a;
    // etc
    parent::afterFind();
}
```